# How does character array with single quote affects an character array without the quotes?

Tags: c, arrays, character

```
char a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
char a[5] = { '1','2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

what is the difference? It does not raise any errors. why?

Answer (score 0):

This will create a character array the way you think it does, with the actual characters `12345`:

```
char a[5] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

This will create a character array with five characters with the ASCII decimal values 1 to 5:

```
char a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Notice also that all of these are unprintables:

[image: ASCII table]

The reason that it doesn't give any errors is because it's a totally valid way of handling characters. A `char` in C is just an ASCII encoded integer.

Answer (score 0):

Characters like `'1'` actually kind of like macros to their actual ASCII values. So saying `'1'` is same as saying `49` since that is its ASCII code value. A `char` type essentially is a signed 8 bit integer by the way so you can assign numbers to it if thats confuse you.

Comment: The signedness of char isn't well-defined. Could as well be unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
char a[5] = { '1','2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

> what is the difference?

The difference is that `1` and `'1'` have different values. `1` has the value 1 and `'1'` has the value of the numeric character code for the character '1'. Assuming the character set is based on ASCII, the ASCII character '1' has the value 49, so `1` will have value 1 and `'1'` will have value 49.

> It does not raise any errors. why?

Both `1` and `'1'` (ASCII 49) are in the range of values supported by `char`, so there is no reason to raise an error or a warning.

Answer (score 0):

In C language, the characters are represented using single quotes.
And anything that is enclosed in a single quote is a character.
Every character has an ASCII code associated with it.

> [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) abbreviated from American Standard Code for Information Interchange, is a character encoding standard for electronic communication. ASCII codes represent text in computers, telecommunications equipment, and other devices.

Example, ASCII code of 'A' is 65

```
char sampleChar = 'A'
char sampleASCII = 65
```

Both character variables sampleChar, sampleASCII provide same value when printed.

So in your case, the compiler does not throw any error because it assumes that you want to store the characters with ASCII values 1,2,3,4 and 5.
But when you print the array,

```
char a[5] = { '1','2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

it will provide characters 1 2 3 4 5 as output. Whereas the first array will not provide any printable output. The characters corresponding to ASCII value 1 2 3 4 5 is used for transmission control.
The ASCII values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 can be found [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)